# Литература, которая затрагивает аспекты написания компонентов

Tags: c#, книги

Собственно нужна литература, которая затрагивает аспекты написания компонентов

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под _компонентами_? Это очень широкое понятие. Посмотрите, например, [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

1. Агуров П.В. "C#. Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio 2005/2008"
2. [How to Create a WPF User Control & Use It in a WPF Application ( C# )](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W)
3. [Пользовательские элементы управления в WPF](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/Template/level18/18_1.php)